# JHipster API authentification

Tags: java, android, rest, jhipster

I used Java Hipster to create my Rest API. I want to use this Rest API in my Java code (I'm developing an Android application). But I don't understand how authenticate me to use my Rest API !

As example, my api is `blabla/api/getUser`. With Firebug I tried to understand how call my API. I simulate a HTTP request POST with parameters `?id=x` and my token in the header (token I got from the request to login from the browser). It's okay, it works, I have my information.

But now, in my java code, I can't send the same HTTP request because I don't know the token. How can I get it ? How can I log me as admin ?
I know : login for admin, password for admin and the URL of my API and parameters I have to send.

Thank's !

Answer (score 2):

***OAUTH2***

POST

**URL:** 
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

**in the header:**
Authorization: eg. 'BASIC Y2xpZW50aWQ6Y2xpZW50c2VjcmV0'
BASE 64 encoding the client details (source: www.base64encode.org/)

Y2xpZW50aWQ6Y2xpZW50c2VjcmV0  == clientid:clientsecret

**in the body:**

- username
- password
- grant_type
- scope

curl -X POST -vu clientid:clientsecret http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read"

edit:
in android look at retrofit by square